# Determine position of row in xslt is every 10th position

Tags: xslt, modulus

here is my current xslt:

```
      <xsl:when test="position()=10">
```

This works, but i have 100 records so it only produces my neccessary html on the 10th record, and nothing more.

what i need now is a dynamic way of saying `when is every ten positions`. i imagine you could use modulus but im having difficulty getting that to work.

Ive tried:

```
      <xsl:when test="position() mod 10">
```

Not sure what the solution is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `<xsl:when test="position() mod 10 = 0">`.